# nodejs how to let for loop wait till running next instance of loop

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-bigquery, async.js

I'm using nodejs with mongodb and bigquery.

so because it seems bigquery only allows 10k inserts per command.

so I made count the main query, and loop to how many pages from 10k.

I get 500k with the count query, so 50 pages or 500 loops.

How to make loop wait till running next page of the loop?

**Code:**

```
var limit = 9999;

mongo_client.connect(mongo_url, function(err, db) {
    var query = {'_id.date_visited':{'$gte':'2016-01-01','$lt':'2016-02-01'}};

    db.collection('my_table').count(query,function(err, count){
        var pages = Math.ceil(count/limit);

        console.log("count: "+count);
        console.log("pages: "+pages);

        for(var page=0;page<pages;page++){
            var skip = page * limit;

            console.log("page: "+page);
            console.log("skip: "+skip);

            //HOW TO MAKE THIS loop wait till running next page of the loop
            db.collection('my_table').find(query).sort({'_id.date_visited':1,'_id.hour_visited':1}).limit(limit).limit(skip).toArray(function(err, db_results) { 
                var documents = [];
                async.each(db_results, function (db_resultsx, cb) {
                    documents.push(db_resultsx);

                    if(documents.length == db_results.length) { 
                        //console.log(documents);
                        bigqueryClient
                          .dataset(dataset)
                          .table('my_table')
                          .insert(documents)
                          .then((insertErrors) => {
                            console.log('Inserted');
                            //documents.forEach((row) => console.log(row));
                            console.error(insertErrors);
                            if (insertErrors && insertErrors.length > 0) {
                              console.log('Insert errors:');
                              insertErrors.forEach((err) => console.error(err));
                            }
                          })
                          .catch((err) => {
                            console.error('ERROR:');
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Well you are already using [`async.each`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each). See this line `async.each(db_results, function (db_resultsx, cb) {` The `cb` there is intended to be executed when you want to signal the next iteration of the loop. Just be careful since you have an `if` statement before another async method, so you should be calling that "callback" both inside the completion of the async method ( bigQuery ) as well as in an `else` condition that needs to pair with the `if`, otherwise we are not signaling to continue the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably replace the for loop with [`async.eachSeries`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachSeries) so then you can decide when the next iteration of the loop happens, and since `async.eachSeries` will only run 1 operation at a time, you won't run into the same error

**EDIT:**

After reading through the code, I think [`async.timesSeries`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#times) (correction from my comment, `async.timesSeries` is the correct option) is a better bet. Here's an example:

```
async.timesSeries(pages, function(page, next)
{
    var skip = page * limit;
    // ... the rest of your code here

    // when you want the next iteration to start, simply call:
    next();
    /*
    which will tell async that the current iteration is complete, 
    and it can do the next one. You can pass 2 parameters to next,
    the first parameter is an error, and if error is not null it will
    immediately call the function below, and the second parameter is an
    item you can pass that will be added to an object which will be sent
    as the second parameter in the function below
    */
},
function(err, coll)
{
    /*
    this function will get called if there's an error
    or when all iterations are completed
    */
});
```

The above code will replace your for loop

Comment: so i need to feed the number of pages to the eachSeries so to loops/iterate that many times?

Comment: I slightly mis-read the intention here, and after looking over your code properly [`async.times`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#times) might be more useful for you, since it will allow callbacks so you only execute the next part of the loop when you want it to, and it will be run `n` number of times

Comment: as default inside the .times it will wait till the code inside finishes till it goes to next loop? or do I need to do something else? I am new with node.

Comment: I've updated my answer, and made a correction, it should be `async.timesSeries` not `async.times` since `async.times` will run multiple at the same time

Comment: the example says async.times

Comment: Gosh, my brain is not working properly today. I think I'm doing too many things at once. Corrected the example

Answer (score 2):

I think a for-loop will not be a good solution for this case, you can loop using recursive calls like this:

```
function performQuery(queryIndex) {
    if( queryIndex >= limit ) return;

    db.exec('query', function(err, db_result) {
        // your code
        performQuery(queryIndex+1);
    })
}
performQuery(0);
```

Comment: I like this idea, but inside the code, it uploads data to bigquery, so I want it to wait till running the next performQuery, or I need to do the performQuery on the bigquery callback?

Comment: if u want to wait till the end of bigquery, run performQuery in bigquery callback

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use recursive promises, and given that you know the count of items in advance, you could do it this way:

```
// Create a "skip" array (there is certainly a nicer way to do it, with a modulo)
var skips = []; 
for(var page=0;page<pages;page++){
    skips.push(page * limit);
}

// Put your mongoDB read and write code in a function
// (that takes skip in entry and returns an array of documents)
var myMongoDBFunc = function (skip) {
    var documents = [];

    db.collection('my_table')
       .find(query)
       .limit(limit)
       .limit(skip)
       .toArray(function(err, db_results) { 
           ...
       });
   ...
   return documents;
}

// And call it with async.concatSeries that will concatenate the results (documents)
async.concatSeries(skips, myMongoDbFunc, function(err, documents) {
    // Will be called at the end
});
```

If you want to optimize and run all the queries in parallel, just replace `concatSeries` by `concat` (but the order won't be guaranteed).

And if you don't care about the returned documents (apparently you just want to write something), maybe you could use `async.series` or `async.parallel` (check by yourself, I don't particularly know `async`).